# Mysql - query relation, tree structure and condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with MySql Query. I have three tables

```
product table
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
| id | title                                                |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | title1                                               |
|  2 | title2                                               |
|  3 | title3                                               |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+

category table
+----+-------+--------+
| id | path  | name   |
+----+-------+--------+
| 1  | 1     | title1 |
| 2  | 1/2   | title2 |
| 3  | 1/2/3 | title3 |
| 4  | 1/4   | title4 |
| 5  | 5     | title5 |
| 6  | 5/6   | title6 |
| 7  | 7     | title7 |
| 8  | 7/8   | title8 |
| 9  | 7/9   | title9 |
+----+-------+--------+

category_product table
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | category_id |
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | 3           |
| 1          | 6           |
| 2          | 2           |
| 3          | 6           |
+------------+-------------+
```

Now I want to select product names of those products that are stored in category 1 and its subcategories and 5 and its subcategories. I have these ideas,

First idea:

```
SELECT 
  product_name
FROM 
  product
WHERE
  id IN SELECT(id FROM product_category WHERE category_id = 1 OR path LIKE "1/%")
  AND id IN SELECT(id FROM product_category WHERE category_id = 5 OR path LIKE "5/%")
```

Here might be many subselects for more categories in condition.

Second idea:

```
SELECT 
  product_name
FROM 
  product p
  INNER JOIN product_category AS prdcat1 ON (prdcat1.product_id = p.id)
  INNER JOIN category AS cat1 ON (cat1.id = prdcat1.category_id AND cat1.id = 1 OR cat1.path LIKE "1/%")
  INNER JOIN product_category AS prdcat2 ON (prdcat2.product_id = p.id)
  INNER JOIN category AS cat2 ON (cat2.id = prdcat2.category_id AND cat2.id = 5 OR cat2.path LIKE "5/%")
```

Hhere might be many JOINs - morever MySql has limit to nubmer of joined tables.

Third idea:

```
SELECT
  product_name
FROM
  product p
  INNER JOIN category_product cp ON (p.id = cp.product_id)
  INNER JOIN category c ON (cp.category_id = c.id)
GROUP BY
  product_id
HAVING 
  (GROUP_CONCAT(c.path) LIKE "1,%" OR GROUP_CONCAT(c.path) LIKE "%,1,%" OR GROUP_CONCAT(c.path) LIKE "%,1/%")
  AND (GROUP_CONCAT(c.path) LIKE "5,%" OR GROUP_CONCAT(c.path) LIKE "%,5,%" OR GROUP_CONCAT(c.path) LIKE "%,5/%");
```

GROUP_CONAT has limit so.

All three approaches are ugly and might be slow. What you mean about it? Is there any general recommended approach to solve this situation? Sorry if a similar question already exists - I did not know how to ask. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the expected result as well? (Having the specified table data.)

Comment: If you would like to search products in multiple categories, then you have to have either a matching number of criteria in there where or have a matching number of queries combined using union.